# Sass: !global flag vs. redefining the variable in the global scope

Tags: sass

Why would you ever use:

```
.highlight {
  $orange: #f60 !global;
  color: $orange;
}
```

...instead of...

```
$orange: #f60;
.highlight {
  color: $orange;
}
```

Why wouldn't you redefine the variable in the global scope rather than use `!global`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One use case for the `!global` flag is for theming. Here's an example:

```scss
$fg-color: black;
$bg-color: gray;

@mixin darkTheme() {
  $fg-color: white !global;
  $bg-color: blue !global;
}

@include darkTheme();

main {
  background: $bg-color;
  color: $fg-color;
}
```

The above SCSS complies to this CSS:

```css
main {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

Using this technique, you can have a theme mixin that cleanly modifies global variables whenever you want.